# Updating a row based on user id

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, dreamweaver

i have one user table with columns : userid, username, password, email, agree_1, comment_1, agree_2, comment_2, ...........

i used this to update the table:

```
UPDATE users SET Agree_1=%s, comment_1=%s, Agree_2=%s, comment_2=%s, Agree_3=%s, comment_3=%s, Agree_4=%s, comment_4=%s, Agree_5=%s, comment_5=%s, Agree_6=%s, comment_6=%s, Agree_7=%s, comment_7=%s, Agree_8=%s, comment_8=%s, Agree_9=%s, comment_9=%s, Agree_10=%s, comment_10=%s, Agree_11=%s, comment_11=%s, Agree_12=%s, comment_12=%s, Agree_13=%s, comment_13=%s, Agree_14=%s, comment_14=%s, Agree_15=%s, comment_15=%s, Agree_16=%s, comment_16=%s, Agree_17=%s, comment_17=%s, WHERE id=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_1'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_1'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_2'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_2'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_3'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_3'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_4'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_4'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_five'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_five'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_six'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_six'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_seven'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_seven'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_eight'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_eight'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_nine'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_nine'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_ten'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_ten'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_eleven'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_eleven'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_twelve'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_twelve'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_thirteen'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_thirteen'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_fourteen'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_fourteen'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_fifteen'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_fifteen'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_sixteen'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_sixteen'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['grp_seventeen'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['text_seventeen'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"));
```

my form has a hidden field which i called id, when i used the above query to update, it was successful, but when i created another user with id of 2, login with his information, use the above query to update the user, it went on to update the user with id of 1, please how do i make it to update any user i create. please help. Below is the query set i used to select from database:

```
$query_draft1b_query = sprintf("SELECT id, Agree_1, comment_1, Agree_2, comment_2, Agree_3, comment_3, Agree_4, comment_4, Agree_5, comment_5, Agree_6, comment_6, Agree_7, comment_7, Agree_8, comment_8, Agree_9, comment_9, Agree_10, comment_10, Agree_11, comment_11, Agree_12, comment_12, Agree_13, comment_13, Agree_14, comment_14, Agree_15, comment_15, Agree_16, comment_16, Agree_17, comment_17, Agree_18, comment_18, Agree_19, comment_19, Agree_20, comment_20, Agree_21, comment_21, Agree_22, comment_22, Agree_23, comment_23, Agree_24, comment_24, Agree_25, comment_25, Agree_26, comment_26, Agree_27, comment_27, Agree_28, comment_28, Agree_29, comment_29, Agree_30a, comment_30a, Agree_31a, comment_31a, Agree_30b, comment_30b, Agree_31b, comment_31b, Agree_32, comment_32, Agree_33, comment_33, Agree_34, comment_34, Agree_35, comment_35, Agree_36, comment_36, Agree_37, comment_37, Agree_38, comment_38, Agree_39, comment_39, Agree_40, comment_40, Agree_41, comment_41, Agree_42, comment_42, Agree_43, comment_43, Agree_44, comment_44, Agree_45, comment_45, Agree_46, comment_46, Agree_47, comment_47, Agree_48, comment_48, Agree_49a, comment_49a, agree_49b, comment_49b, Agree_50, comment_50 FROM users WHERE id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_draft1b_query, "int"));$draft1b_query = mysql_query($query_draft1b_query, $NAWFIA_1) or die(mysql_error());$row_draft1b_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($draft1b_query);$totalRows_draft1b_query = mysql_num_rows($draft1b_query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use structure

```
UPDATE [table] SET [Column] = [Value] WHERE id = [id]
```

In with your problem

```
Update users Set .... WHERE id = 2
```

But I think your database design is not good. Please split it to two table (comments, users).
In comments, use a foreign key to users.

Comment: ok so which one do u think i should make a primary key? how do i go about that?

Comment: Please create 2 two tables: 1/ Users(id, username) and 2/ Comments(id, id_users, agree, comment). id is primary key, you can set it int auto increment.

Comment: i am using dream weaver, the above code works, but when i logging with the id of 2 or 3, and comment or insert record to the database, it will still update the one of user id of 1. please help  me

Comment: no i need a way to save the id from the session, so that when user with id of 2 or 3 loggs in, it will update the record of the user with id of 2 or 3.

Comment: Please check id value in SESSION. Please sure that is true value. I think you are having problem with value in session. That is wrong value.